# Adding n times new parameters while keeping the starting point

Tags: javascript, variables

I am building basically a distance calculator.
User inputs origin point and then the values of x and y, which will be added to the origin's xy.
But after he/she inputs those there might come a reason to add more to x and y.
For that under the original equations answer field I will add another input field upon the completion of the original function.

How to make it this way that no matter how many times the user inputs corrections to x and y  new input fields are created under the output field of the last calculation and new inputs are added to the last result, not to the original and then run the whole calculation again? I know that one way would be to make duplicate functions, which define new inputs as new variables - first x, then x1, then x2 and so on but this would not be defined as good practice probably as it would repeat itself a lot. How to define new input field's id's as x+n?

I have to use vanilla javascript, the program has to run offline on Windows Mobile 6.1 device. Also I am quite new to coding, so if you could point me in the right direction (I can't define the problem better at the moment) I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're just in need of harvesting form input without doing a real submit. I made a mock up of what this is very simply. Tie in your logic here or elsewhere to process the global array of inputs.

Also note stack overflow's online editor has some odd behavior for submitting, but this should be okay locally.

```js
var inputs = [];

function add() {
  var xElem = document.getElementById("x");
  var yElem = document.getElementById("y");

  var xValue = xElem.value;
  var yValue = yElem.value;

  inputs.push({
    "x": xValue,
    "y": yValue
  });

  xElem.value = "";
  yElem.value = "";

  console.log(inputs);
  return false; // Prevents form from "submitting"

}
```

```html
<form id="inputform" onsubmit="add()">
  <input id="x" placeholder="x" /><br>
  <input id="y" placeholder="y" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```